# Javascript show/hide does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, show-hide

In order to save last hair on my head, I am asking your help.

I have an imagemap with interactive areas. Plus I have a script which shows and hides text field in the right side of the map. An example world map, I press on USA - text field appears with information about it, I press on Europe - Europe information appears instead of USA.

The script I use:

```
function showonlyonev2(thechosenone) {
  var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
        name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
        if (name == 'adresas' || name == 'intro') {
              if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                    if (newboxes[x].style.display == 'block') {
                          newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    else {
                          newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                    }
              }else {
                    newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
              }            }      }}
```

This I use for href: `href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes1-2');"`
This I use to name DIVs: `<div class="adresas" id="newboxes1-2">`

Every browser displays fine, except Internet Explorer 8 (grr!!)
I does not work with IE8.

Any ideas how to make that dumb browser to run my script? (it runs other scripts, except this one).

Regards,
Baseckas

Comment: have u tried using onclick rather than in href... href="#" onclick="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes1-2');"

Comment: Sure, use the debugger and have IE tell you why it no worky. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say this :

```
 name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class")?newboxes[x].getAttribute("class"): newboxes[x].getAttribute("className");
```

Comment: @Baseckas ur welcome, please take the time to "accept" the answer if you think it solved your problem.